# Mail:Send with Custom Module and Email Template

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am currently creating a module to execute a set of codes on hookActionProductCancel. Module is running well and I would like to send out an email after execution.

```
$template_path = $this->local_path . 'mails/';

Mail::Send((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')),
 'xxx', //need to change the template directory to point to custom module
 'Subject',
 array(
   '{aaa}' => $bbb,
   '{bbb}' => $ccc,
   '{ccc}' => $ddd,
   '{ddd}' => $eee
 ),
 $to,
 null, null, null);
```

I have created the templates and place the files as follow:

1. ../mails/en/xxx.html
2. ../mails/en/xxx.txt

While I understand the default navigation for email templates are above, how do I use templates placed in my custom modules directory?

I have created a directory - ../modules/custommodule/mails/ and placed both files but am not successful in pointing to it.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify template path in [Mail::Send()](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/classes/Mail.php#L87) .

You can see that 11th parameter is `$template_path` so you just need to specify that (if you're calling send method from main module class you can use `$this->local_path . 'mails/'`). The `$template_path` parameter must be server file path not URI because the method uses `file_exists()` to check if a template exists. Method will extract from your module path that it is in fact a custom module template.

Now the method will first check if you have mail template in

`themes/shop_theme/modules/mymodule/mails/iso_lang/xxx.html`

then in

`modules/mymodule/mails/iso_lang/xxx.html`

and load the first template it finds. Same goes for txt files.

**Edit:**

How to execute method correctly:

```
Mail::Send(
    (int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')),
    'xxx', //need to change the template directory to point to custom module
    'Subject',
    array(
       '{aaa}' => $bbb,
       '{bbb}' => $ccc,
       '{ccc}' => $ddd,
       '{ddd}' => $eee
    ),
    $to,
    null, 
    null, 
    null,
    null,
    null,
    $this->local_path . 'mails/' // 11th parameter is template path
)
```

Comment: I have tried $template_path = '../modules/custommodule/mails/'; but it is still returning the error - The following e-mail template is missing: /var/www/domain/public_html/mails/en/xxx.txt.... Am I missing something? It is still pointing to the original path

Comment: Did you try with `$this->local_path . 'mails/'`?

Comment: Yes, I did... I tried that and it returned me the same error, so I tried another way. Seems like it is still pointing to mails/en though...

Comment: Do I need to change anything in Mail:Send with regards to the template?

Comment: Can you update your question with how you are calling `Mail::send()`? I tested in my dev instance and it's working just fine.

Comment: I have edited the codes in my post. I have included $template_path before calling Mail::Send().... I guess I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Oh my.... thank you so much for your assistance. Precisely why I am facing this issue, the codes are wrong.

Comment: Created /en folder that was missing and I cannot thank you enough for this priceless guidance. It is working perfectly fine. Now I understand Mail::Send() better. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

yes, I agree with 'TheDrot'  you have to pass 11th parameter correctly and if you face an error with

`$this->local_path . 'mails/'`

than try

```
$this->module->getLocalPath().'mails/'
```

Comment: Thank you. All is well now with TheDrot's suggestion.